Generate PDF and append into database
The issue I encounter is that when I try to upload it as blob into the database. The blob generated in the database seems not working (just some C::location data instead of the PDF content).Hence, I try to think if I can just fetched the generated PDF and upload the PDF into the database. This code is currently functioning only until the generate PDF part. The PDF do generate but the file did not uploaded into the database
This is the JavaScript that I use to generate the pdf
    src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf-invoice-template@1.4.0/dist/index.js"
function generatePDF() {
    var pdfObject = jsPDFInvoiceTemplate.default(props);

    var csrfToken = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('pdfData', pdfObject);
    // Send PDF data to Laravel controller for saving
    $.ajax({
        url: '/save-pdf',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        contentType: false, // Don't set contentType manually, let jQuery handle it
        processData: false, // Don't process the data, let jQuery handle it
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrfToken
        },
        success: function(response) {
            // Handle success response
            console.log('PDF saved successfully. PDF ID:', response.pdfId);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            // Handle error response
            console.error('Error saving PDF:', error);
        }
    });
}


var props = {
    outputType: jsPDFInvoiceTemplate.OutputType.Save,
    returnJsPDFDocObject: true,
    fileName: "Invoice 2021",
    orientationLandscape: false,
    logo: {
        src: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/edisonneza/jspdf-invoice-template/demo/images/logo.png",
        type: 'PNG', //optional, when src= data:uri (nodejs case)
        width: 53.33, //aspect ratio = width/height
        height: 26.66,
        margin: {
            top: 0, //negative or positive num, from the current position
            left: 0 //negative or positive num, from the current position
        }
    },
    stamp: {
        inAllPages: true, //by default = false, just in the last page
        src: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/edisonneza/jspdf-invoice-template/demo/images/qr_code.jpg",
        type: 'JPG', //optional, when src= data:uri (nodejs case)
        width: 20, //aspect ratio = width/height
        height: 20,
        margin: {
            top: 0, //negative or positive num, from the current position
            left: 0 //negative or positive num, from the current position
        }
    },
    business: {
        name: "Business Name",
        address: "Albania, Tirane ish-Dogana, Durres 2001",
        phone: "(+355) 069 11 11 111",
        email: "email@example.com",
        email_1: "info@example.al",
        website: "www.example.al",
    },
    contact: {
        label: "Invoice issued for:",
        name: "Client Name",
        address: "Albania, Tirane, Astir",
        phone: "(+355) 069 22 22 222",
        email: "client@website.al",
        otherInfo: "www.website.al",
    },
    invoice: {
        label: "Invoice #: ",
        num: 19,
        invDate: "Payment Date: 01/01/2021 18:12",
        invGenDate: "Invoice Date: 02/02/2021 10:17",
        headerBorder: false,
        tableBodyBorder: false,
        header: [
          {
            title: "#",
            style: {
              width: 10
            }
          },
          {
            title: "Title",
            style: {
              width: 30
            }
          },
          {
            title: "Description",
            style: {
              width: 80
            }
          },
          { title: "Price"},
          { title: "Quantity"},
          { title: "Unit"},
          { title: "Total"}
        ],
        table: Array.from(Array(10), (item, index)=>([
            index + 1,
            "There are many variations ",
            "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text dummy text ",
            200.5,
            4.5,
            "m2",
            400.5
        ])),
        additionalRows: [{
            col1: 'Total:',
            col2: '145,250.50',
            col3: 'ALL',
            style: {
                fontSize: 14 //optional, default 12
            }
        },
        {
            col1: 'VAT:',
            col2: '20',
            col3: '%',
            style: {
                fontSize: 10 //optional, default 12
            }
        },
        {
            col1: 'SubTotal:',
            col2: '116,199.90',
            col3: 'ALL',
            style: {
                fontSize: 10 //optional, default 12
            }
        }],
        invDescLabel: "Invoice Note",
        invDesc: "There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary.",
    },
    footer: {
        text: "The invoice is created on a computer and is valid without the signature and stamp.",
    },
    pageEnable: true,
    pageLabel: "Page ",
};

I declared the laravel web.php route
This is the controller function
public function savePDF(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $username = Session::get('username');
            // // Get the PDF data from the request
            // $pdfData = $request->input('pdfData');
            $pdfData = $request->file('pdfData');
            // Save the PDF data to the database using Eloquent
            $pdf = new pdfsaver();
            $pdf->username = $username;
            $pdf->files = $pdfData;
            $pdf->save();

            // Respond with success message and PDF ID
            return response()->json(['success' => true, 'pdfId' => $pdf->id]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Log the error

            // Respond with an error message
            return response()->json(['success' => false, 'error' => 'Error saving PDF']);
        }
    }


when you do formData.append, you should probably use formData.append('pdfData', pdfObject.blob);

Edit your original question if you need to update it
